Which was the reason the groups in the 1950 FIFA World Cup were created so unevenly in the amount of teams per group?
In the 1950 FIFA World Cup, there were 13 teams in the tournament. The most logical thing would have been to create 3 groups of 3 teams and one group of 4 teams, so later you could organize the final round with 4 teams coming first in their own groups.
However, they created 2 groups of 4 teams, 1 group of 3 teams, and 1 group of 2 teams. The teams in the group of 2 were in a clear important advantage against the groups of 4 teams.
Why were the groups in the 1950 FIFA World Cup were created so unevenly in the number of teams per group?

There should have been fifteen teams, with three pools of four teams each, and a pool of three teams. These were drawn in May 1950, with India in Group 3 and France in Group 4.
Both withdrew from the tournament, India for a variety of reasons, France for the significant travel between venues. With less than a month between draw and matches beginning in June 1950, it was not possible to invite other teams, especially those who had already turned it down.

Was it not possible to reshuffle the groups to make them more even?

With venues, accommodation, travel already arranged? I doubt it would have been possible now.

Draw was on 22nd May, only four weeks before the first match (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1950_FIFA_World_Cup). In 1950 in a huge country like Brazil, you can't reorganize that quickly.
